# How should I implement Doctor and Patient in one users table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, data-structures, devise

I want to implement these models:

```
Doctor # maybe I should use STI Doctor < User
 has_many :cases
Patient
 has_many :cases
Case # each case has one pair of doctor and patient
 belongs_to :doctor
 belongs_to :patient
```

But I have User model right now with Devise authentication. What fields should have `cases` table and do I need to change something in associations to make that working?

Doctor and User should be able to sign in to the app.

So I think `cases` table should have something like `patient_id` and `doctor_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Case` needs a `doctor_id` and a `patient_id`. These could either reference `Doctor` and `Patient` as separate models:

```
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cases
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor
  belongs_to :patient
end
```

Or they could reference `User` in general (probably with some kind of `role` field):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctor_cases, class_name: "Case", foreign_key: "doctor_id"
  has_many :patient_cases, class_name: "Case", foreign_key: "patient_id"
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :patient, class_name: "User"
end
```

Now a user could be a doctor in one case and a patient in another case :-)

Comment: For patient and doctor you should change them to ``Case < User`` I think

Comment: @regedarek yes, if you want STI.

Answer (score 0):

I think `class_name` will work

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'doctor_id'
  has_many :patients, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'patient_id'
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'doctor_id'
  belongs_to :patient, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'patient_id'
end
```